# How to give support for PostgreSQL in my application

Tags: database, postgresql, model-view-controller, connection-string

I am going to give support for `PostgreSQL` in my application. Can anyone suggest what are the things need to be considered ?

1. Whether it is `open source software` ?
2. what is `version` need to install ?
3. How PostgreSQL is different from `SQL server/SQL CE/My SQL`
4. About `connection string` ?

Please suggest me with this... Any help would be appreciated.. :)

Comment: What platform does your app run on? What is it written in? Given your questions I'm assuming probably C# and .NET.

Comment: I am using c# only.

Comment: OK, so start with nPgSQL and possibly Entity Framework, then.

Answer (score 1):

Try https://www.postgresql.org/; that should cover a lot of questions you have asked.

1. PostgreSQL is Open Source; they claim to be "The world's most advanced open source database". It's release under the term of the [PostgreSQL License](https://opensource.org/licenses/postgresql).
2. You should always go with the latest version (9.5.x if you are looking for a GA version; 9.6.x if you are ok with going with Beta) unless you have a specific need to stay with a lower version
3. There are numerous differences in architecture, storage and syntax areas. But PostgreSQL is a database server just like SQL Server, SQL CE or MySQL, and at the minimum executes SQL statements for you. You will need to Google 'Postgres vs MySQL' or 'Postgres vs SQL Server' or similar. You will find a lot of material to read upon (example: [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/sqlite-vs-mysql-vs-postgresql-a-comparison-of-relational-database-management-systems))
4. Are you looking for a JDBC connection string? If no, then what's your programming language? If it's Java, the JDBC URL looks like this: `jdbc:postgresql://host[:port]/database`

Comment: I am using c# in my application.